# Program exits while calling await function

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-web-api, async-await

---

Hello, I want to consume REST api. I use code like this:

```
namespace test2
{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestRest t = new TestRest();
        t.Run();
    }
}

public class TestRest
{
    public TestRest() { }

    public async void Run()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://community-league-of-legends.p.mashape.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Mashape-Authorization", "tcsgoutBcXP5Lu5L2jYBOu4qeXehseiH");
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/v1.0/euw/summoner/getSummonerByName/NICK_FROM_GAME");

        JObject response2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()) as JObject;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> j in response2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key:{0} Value:{1}", j.Key, j.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

}

But while calling method:

```
await client.getAsync("...
```

program is exiting. Please help me, its simple console app to consume simple api and i can not manage this :(

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems here:

- You've got a `void` async method, which is almost always a bad idea unless it's meant to be an event handler. You should generally make an async method return `Task` where you'd normally write a `void` synchronous method.
- Your app is exiting because there are no foreground threads left running. There'll be a continuation which *would* fire if the response returned while the process was still alive - but nothing to keep the process alive.

The simplest fix is to address both at the same time - just make the async method return `Task`, and then use:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestRest t = new TestRest();
    t.Run().Wait();
}
```

Note that that would be a really bad idea in a WinForms app, as waiting on a `Task` in the UI thread would basically cause a deadlock. However, in a console app there's no equivalent of the UI thread, so task continuations are scheduled on the thread pool - your "main" thread will block, the continuation in your async method will run on a thread pool thread, and then when that's completed the task that the main thread is waiting for will complete.

Comment: Thank but I have another question. Basicly i'm trying to consume this api. Maybe you know a simple way to do this without using awaits? I would like use this api in future in application with UI (windows phone + silverlight).

Comment: @Ellbar: You'd basically have to make the main thread sleep. But fundamentally it's a badly designed API, and it should be fixed.

Comment: Could you give me a real example in code because i'm fighting with this api so long with no effects :(

Comment: @Ellbar: I don't know what you mean. I've told you what you need to do with the code - just change the return type of `TestRest.Run` to `Task`, and wait for it when you call it...

Comment: PS: do you know any good book/article/site about delegates, func, await, async, task, action etc? I need to learnabout this stuff :(

Comment: @Ellbar: Well you've given a pretty broad list of topics there. My own C# in Depth covers them, but I'd expect pretty much any good C# book to do so too.